# @ManyToMany relation not save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I have some entities with`@ManyToMany` relation:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "buses_drivers",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "driver_id_inner", referencedColumnName = "driver_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "bus_id_inner", referencedColumnName = "bus_id"))
private List<Bus> buses;
```

and

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "buses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Driver> drivers;
```

When execute saving `Driver` model with some `Bus` models, all ok. Tables `buses_drivers` store all keys those entities. But when saving `Bus` model with drivers, table doesn't change. I think problem with `inverseJoinColmns` mapping.

Comment: or maybe the problem is in your persistence code? Perhaps posting it would help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. In a bidirectional many-to-many association one side has to be the inverse side. In your case it is the `Bus` side because it contains [`mappedBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#mappedBy--):

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship
>   is unidirectional.

That means that `Driver` is the owner of the association and Hibernate will only check that side when maintaining the association.

Answer (score 8):

You should definitely redesign your relations.

Without even getting into the problems with your current save scenario, with bidirectional `@ManyToMany` + `CascadeType.ALL`, you're destined to get even more troubles.

For example, deleting one `bus` will due to cascade, delete all its drivers, which due to cascade again, will delete all its buses. You'll basically end up deleting much more than you probably want. Also, check the SQL generated by these mappings, you'll most likely notice that its far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

For people doesn't understand from the accepted answer. This is more appropriate : [Java: saving entities with ManyToMany association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991124/java-saving-entities-with-manytomany-association)

I came across with this problem in test cases when filling test data.

**When there is an owning side you just can save child just with owner.**