# Hibernate HQL: Many to many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have 2 tables represented by **2 beans:ProcessType and Typology.**

On the DB there is a third table that represent the many to many realtion between those two tables, the table doesen't have a bean and is called **process_type_typology**

The table has 2 columns: **typology and process_type**

On ProcessType i have the following attribute that represents the relation:

```
          @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinTable(name = "process_types_typology" ,
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "process_type")} ,
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "typology")})
          private Set<Typology> typologies = new HashSet<Typology>(0);
```

And then on Typology:

```
          @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
          @JoinTable(name = "process_types_typology" ,
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "typology")} ,
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "process_type")})
          private Set<ProcessType> processTypes = new HashSet<ProcessType>(0);
```

How can i make a join between those 2 tables? The third table is not mapped so i dont' have idea.

On SQL the query is this:

```
 from processType inner join process_types_typology ptt on pt.id_process_type=ptt_.process_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join `ProcessType` and `Typology`, Hibernate will take care to mention relationship table in the generated SQL:

```
from ProcessType pt join pt.typologies t
```

Also, since the association is bidirectional, make sure to declare one side to be [inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36241830/4754790).