# Java: saving entities with ManyToMany association

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I'm having trouble saving entities with ManyToMany associations. I've read some posts regarding this but came to no conclusion.
I have tow entities with ManyToMany association. I've read that the correct way to create this entities was creating the association between them and not create a third entity to hold the association, so I implemented it this way. When I run the code, it creates a third FK table as expected, but when I try to save new objects with this association it happens one of two things:

- In the first example I create the RawMaterial entity first and, then, I create the Product entity. This action returns the error: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist;
- The second example, I create the Product entity first. Then I create the RawMaterial entity and save it. It successfully creates both lines on database but it doesn't create any association on the FK table.

My code is:

Product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    //Product attributes
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_raw_material",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "raw_material_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private Set<RawMaterial> rawMaterialList = new HashSet<>();
    //Getters and setters
}
```

RawMaterial entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "raw_materials",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = 
    {"bar_code"}),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
public class RawMaterial {
    
     //RawMaterial attributes
     ...
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rawMaterialList")
    private Set<Product> productsList = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters
```

}

*First attempt to create new Product and RawMaterial entities:*

```
RawMaterial material = new RawMaterial("barcode", "name", 
    LocalDateTime.now(), 
    LocalDateTime.now());
Set<RawMaterial> materialsList = new HashSet<>();
RawMaterial savedMaterial = rawMaterialRepository.save(material);
materialsList.add(savedMaterial);

Product product = new Product("code", "name", materialsList, 
    LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());
Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
```

**This example returns the error when trying to persist the Product entity:** org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist.

Second attempt:

```
Product product = new Product("code", "name", null, 
    LocalDateTime.now(), 
    LocalDateTime.now());
Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);

Set<Product> productsSet = new HashSet<>();
productsSet.add(savedProduct);
RawMaterial material = new RawMaterial("barcode", "name", 
    LocalDateTime.now(), 
    LocalDateTime.now());
material.getProductsList().add(productsSet.stream()
    .iterator().next());
rawMaterialRapository.save(material);
```

This creates a new entry on each table but creates nothing on the association table (the product_raw_material association table that was automatically generated).

I don't know if I should specify an entity to hold the association or if I'm missing something on repository. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@Transactional
public Product saveProduct() {
    RawMaterial material = new RawMaterial("barcode", "name", 
        LocalDateTime.now(), 
        LocalDateTime.now());

    Set<RawMaterial> materialsList = new HashSet<>();
    materialsList.add(material);

    Product product = new Product("code", "name", materialsList, 
        LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());
    material.getProductsList().add(product);

    return productRepository.save(product);
}
```

Comment: That worked, and I think I got it. I have to create the RawMaterial entity first but can not persist it through RawMaterialRepository, instead, I have to create a Product (or get an existing one), add that raw material to the list of products rawMaterials and, then, persist only the Product. It's easier than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your design the owner of the association is **RawMaterial**
because of you used `mappedBy` attribute as RawMaterial. That's fine but when you want to persist RawMaterial it tries to execute what is responsible for (creating product_raw_material and inserting row with FKs of association sides) but there is no Product record which can be used. That's why you get the error you describe.

Comment: Yes, I understood that and already tested that implementation but then I had another problem as described on the post. Thanks for your response.